# Reading cookie value does only work sometimes

Tags: javascript, cookies, joomla

at first i want to make a short description of the process containing the problem:

If someone clicks one of our company's AdWords ads and comes on our website i'm creating a cookie "adwords" with the value "true" via Google Tag Manager (Trigger: URL contains "?gclid="). The cookie is only set with "true", a cookie with "false" is not created at any point.

Then, when someone clicks on our contact form link, i read the value from the "adwords"-cookie and pass it into a blind field in the contact form. When the user clicks the "send" button, i get an email containing his data including the cookie value.

Everytime i try it myself it works perfectly. But when i compare the number of conversions in my AdWords-account with the data i get from my contact form it seems to be working only sometimes for other users.

I'm a beginner in javascript so maybe theres a error in reasoning in my script (its mostly from w3schools):

```
function getAdwordsCookie(cname) {
var name = cname + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') {
        c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
        return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
}
return "false";
```

}

```
function SetAdwordsField() {
proforms.setValue(21,getAdwordsCookie("adwords"));
```

}

Can someone help please?

Comment: Some people disable cookies - I know, right!! How weird is that?!

Comment: i know, but that would mean that 90% of our website visitors do that.

Answer (score -1):

If you want get getCookies function,you can try blow:

```
function getCookie(c_name) {
if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
    c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
    if (c_start != -1) {
        c_start = c_start + c_name.length + 1;
        c_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start);
        if (c_end == -1) c_end = document.cookie.length;
        return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start, c_end));
    }
}
return "";
}
```

Comment: this is just a different way of getting the cookie, how does this answer the question

Comment: sorry! I think he should give us the error that why it is not work sometimes!

Comment: really? What error are you talking about? The "error in reasoning"? Do you see an error in his code?

Comment: is the line "return "false"; at the wrong point in the code? that is the only thing i changed from the w3schools function. I do not get an error, if i try it it works, but not with every other user, only some.

Comment: you can use the debug in chrome and find out!

Answer (score -1):

use my repository [Milk JS](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GlowStone07/Milk-JS/main/src/milk.js) in github.

```html
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GlowStone07/Milk-JS/main/src/milk.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

use the function `get` then the cookie name, returns cookie value.

FULL EXAMPLE:

```js
//set new cookie
set("name", "John Doe");
//log the cookie's value
console log(get("name'));
//clear all cookies
clear();
//expected output: John Doe
```